# Need help to shorten this piece of code as I keep getting a Time Limit Exceeded error on LeetCode

Tags: java, arrays, database

I submitted this code on LeetCode recently and kept getting a Time Limit Exceeded error. I am new to Java and would like help shortening it. Here is some information about the question:

Given an integer array nums and an integer val, remove all occurrences of val in nums in-place. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val.

Consider the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:

Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
Return k.
Custom Judge:

The judge will test your solution with the following code:

```
    int[] nums = [...]; // Input array
    int val = ...; // Value to remove
    int[] expectedNums = [...]; // The expected answer with correct length.
                            // It is sorted with no values equaling val.

    int k = removeElement(nums, val); // Calls your implementation

    assert k == expectedNums.length;
    sort(nums, 0, k); // Sort the first k elements of nums
    for (int i = 0; i < actualLength; i++) {
        assert nums[i] == expectedNums[i];
    }
```

If all assertions pass, then your solution will be accepted.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3
Output: 2, nums = [2,2,*,*]
Explanation: Your function should return k = 2, with the first two elements of nums being 2.
It does not matter what you leave beyond the returned k (hence they are underscores).

Example 2:

Input: nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2], val = 2
Output: 5, nums = [0,1,4,0,3,*,*,_]
Explanation: Your function should return k = 5, with the first five elements of nums containing 0, 0, 1, 3, and 4.
Note that the five elements can be returned in any order.
It does not matter what you leave beyond the returned k (hence they are underscores).

Constraints:

```
0 <= nums.length <= 100
0 <= nums[i] <= 50
0 <= val <= 100
```

Here is the code I submitted:

```
    class Solution {
        public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        
            int k = 0;
            int numOfVal = 0;
        
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
                if (nums[i] == val) {
                    nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
                    numOfVal++;
                }
                else {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        
            while (numOfVal != 0) {
                val--;
            }
            return k;
        }
    }
```

I think the code works since I didn't get any errors, but I can't check it's correctness with all the test cases due to the Time Limit Exceeded error!

P.S. I'm new to Stack Overflow as well so forgive me if my post is hard to read or confusing, I'll try to improve that next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not correct. When you find an element equal to `val`, you overwrite it with `nums[i] = nums[i + 1];`. If `nums[i + 1]` is also equal to `val`, this will give you an incorrect result.

Besides, your `while` loop causes an infinite loop and does nothing meaningful. That's why you reach the time limit.

You should eliminate the `while` loop. And in the `for` loop you should assign to `nums[i]` a value that is different than `val`. I'd take the value with the highest index that is not equal to `val` and wasn't already used.

I believe this should work:

```
class Solution {
    public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        int k = 0;
        int last = nums.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == val) {
                while (nums[last] == val) {
                  last--;
                }
                if (i < last) {
                    nums[i] = nums[last];
                    last--;
                    k++;
                }
            } else {
              k++;
            }
        }

        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! I tried it out and it didn't quite work for this test case: 

Input: [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2] 2 

Output: [0,1,4,4,3,0]

Expected: [0,1,4,0,3]

Comment: @AmaanUdhay you're right. I forgot to decrement `last` after the assignment. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your while is running forever bro. if you need to have some stop condition, if numOfVal != 0 you will be decreasing val infinite times. Ussualy you want to decrease or increase inside the while brackets the same variable that you have in the while condition.
EX:

```
int a = 99;
while (a!=0) {
a--;
}
```

so after 100 iterations your while stops. But you are never updating numOfVal so your while is something like this

```
int a = 99;
int b = 0;
while (a!=0) {
b--;
}
```

b will decrease forever and a=99 will nver change so the while is not going to stop.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! I tried this adjustment and it failed on this test case:

Input:
[0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]
2

Output:
[0,1,2,3,3]

Expected:
[0,1,4,0,3]